# Rails routes set post and link to set method to post but still wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

The function is, a user can press like to tweet, and redirect to the same page.

Here's my route

```
resources :tweets, only: [:index, :create] do

  member do               
    post :like
  end

end
```

end

and screenshot for checking with rails routes

[image]

And here's the view

```
<%= link_to "Like", like_tweet_path(tweet.id), method: :post %>
```

But when I press Like, there's an error message below.

[image]

What's happened here?

Can anyone help me... Thanks

Comment: Above should work, please try by reloading page or restarting server

Comment: For some reason your `method: :post` is not working. Can you confirm the presence of `rails_ujs` or `jquery_ujs` in your `application.js`

Comment: but i think you can also use `get` method instead if `post`

Comment: Must be some JS triggering somewhere else causing this.

Comment: Post your controller method

Comment: @fool-dev controller method has nothing to do here since it is a routing error, it didn't even get to the controller.

Comment: The error says the server received a `[GET]` request, while in your routes and view you defined the route and link as `POST`. From the [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) documentation: "Note that if the user has JavaScript disabled, the request will fall back to using GET." So you should check what @AneesMuhammed said.